# Closure of a domain

Tags: general-topology

A closure of a set $A$ is a the smallest closed set contains $A$.

Consider two domains $\Omega_1$ and $\Omega_2$ of respective boundaries $\Gamma_1$ and $\Gamma_2$.

[image]

I am trying to understand geometrically the closure of domain $\Omega_1$. At the end it is the set of all point contained within the area of $\Gamma_1$.

How can we understand $\overline{\Omega_1}$ and the notion $\Gamma_2 \cap \overline{\Omega_1}=\emptyset$?

**Editing my question to simplify my question more:**

In other words, what is the difference between $\Gamma_2\cap\Gamma_1$, $\Gamma_2\cap\overline{\Omega_1}$ and $\Gamma_2 \cap \partial \Omega_1$?

Comment: Do you mean $\Gamma_1 \cap \overline{\Omega_2}=\emptyset$?

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy No, this comes to explain the fact if $\Omega_2$ was growing then it's boundary $\Gamma_2$ will not cross $\Omega_1$ boundary. My question is why we used closure instead of $\Gamma_1$.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy but in any case, what does what you said mean? Can you explain it in words? What is $\overline{\Omega_2}$ on the figure?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here, $\Gamma_{1}$ is the boundary of the set $\Omega_{1}$, i.e. $\Gamma_{1} = \partial \Omega_{1}$ (the partial is just another notation for boundary). This boundary does not intersect $\Gamma_{2}$ and $\Omega_{2}$ of course, so $\Gamma_{2}\cap \Gamma_{1} = \Gamma_{1} \cap \Omega_{2} = \emptyset $.

$\overline{\Omega}_{1}$ is all what is inside $\Gamma_{1}$, union $\Gamma_{1}$. Of course, $\Gamma_{2}$ is inside $\Omega_{1}$ which is itself inside $\overline{\Omega}_{1}$, so $\Gamma_{2}\cap \overline{\Omega_{1}} = \Gamma_{2} \neq \emptyset$